# After Nginx update - site broken

Tags: nginx, debian

The website worked with no issues for years. I incrementally perform updates but this time it completely messed up. Now I get the default "welcome to Nginx" page. I double checked all my folder locations etc. but can't figure this out. Not sure what's causing this breakdonw. I traced everything to its exact folder locations. Interestingly enough I can't find the index.html of the default welcome to Nginx page. I am now at Nginx 1.12.0 and Debian 8.7

Here is the conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name NAME.com www.NAME.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    #server_name NAME.com www.NAME.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/NAME.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/NAME.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:128m;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31557600; includeSubDomains";
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;  

    index index.html index.htm;    

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/ {
    allow all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|svg|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    }

   gzip  on;
   gzip_comp_level  1;
   gzip_min_length  1000;
   gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
   gzip_types       text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;
   gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
   gzip_vary on;
   gzip_buffers 16 8k;

   server_tokens off;
   add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
   add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
}
```

Finally here is the nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  65536;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

   #sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay    on;

    client_body_timeout 3m;
    client_header_timeout 3m;
    keepalive_timeout 40;
    send_timeout 3m;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRAZY - so it looks like when NGINX updated, it replaces the index.html file to the default "welcome to Nginx" html file. I had a backup so I lucked out but what nonsense. Why would they replace the index.html file!! I saw the file size and just opened the code to check - otherwise I would have never found out.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `server_name` in your server block for port 443. Are you sure that is the server block that serves your request?
Check for a default file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. It would have the keyword `default_server` in its `listen`-directive.

Comment: yeah pretty sure that is the server block. I uncommented that line and I remember uncommenting caused issues several months ago. I don't have /etc/nginx/sites-enabled folder.

Comment: Then what is the location of the file with your server blocks? Are there any other configuration files in that directory?

Comment: I checked /usr/local/nginx/conf and  /usr/local/etc/nginx - there is no conf file. The only locations are Server Block: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
Nginx config: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: You can try to comment the whole server block and insert a redirection, for example to `https://www.example.com`, just to see it really is that block. Are your website files on the directory `/usr/share/nginx/html` ?